# Selectable CAN bus split termination

Tags: switches, opto-isolator, can, termination, split

I am designing a CAN device where the user may switch between it being the end device and thus with terminators or vice versa.

Now, there is no need to drive it digitally using MCU, I would actually prefer using a DPDT (or DPST) slide switch only. However, I am not sure if it's a good idea to connect it directly like this:

[image: Split termination using directly DPDT switch]

A solution using optocouplers seems to be rather frequent from what I've seen and it seems more clean - separating the CAN from the switch - but I am not sure if it is not an overkill considering driving it from MCU is not used:

[image: Split termination using photocouplers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem passing the CAN signal through a switch, you don't need the complexity and cost of the optos if you are not driving it from a logic source. The switch should be a signal (not power rated) switch, with gold contacts for low resistance at low currents and voltages. I don't see why you need DPDT, DPST is sufficient, and more commonly available e.g. as DIP switches.

There is some advantage in the second schematic with optos - you could feed both opto LEDs from the same SPST switch, which simplifies the switch requirement. Another improvement would be to series the opto LEDs and recalculate the 720R resistor for that, saving 3mA from your 3.3V supply.

Comment: Thank you, my worry is also the voltage rating of switches, where if I understand correctly - when using the CAN the rating should be at least 24 V?

Comment: I can't see that being a problem. While there might be some fault conditions where you could get 24V across the switch, it is not a normal condition and the quick check of DIP switches I did [showed that they are rated for 24V](https://www.mouser.co.uk/Electromechanical/Switches/DIP-Switches-SIP-Switches/_/N-5g2s?Keyword=dip+switch&FS=True).

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a whole lot of an experience with CAN but considering that it is a differential signal of MHz I would not be worried to use small SMT switches (your first option).

In case you could do this as assembly variant to assemble the termination parts or not, problem will be easier and you save switches.