# CAN bus termination resistor

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, can, transceiver, termination

I'm trying to design a CAN device where the user can select which device is the beginning/end device and activate the 120 ohm resistor accordingly. I've seen some examples using a switch, but I'm wondering if there's any solution/ways to switch it with the GPIO from a microcontroller?

For example if there's 4 devices, and the user select Device A and Device D as the beginning and the end device, how do I only activate the 120ohm termination resistor on Device A and D and not activate (open circuit) on Device B and C?

I'm using [MCP2544](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP2542FD-MCP2542WFD-4WFD-Data-Sheet-DS20005514C.pdf) as my transceiver and [STM32L552ZET6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l552qe.pdf) as my microcontroller and the CAN connector will be a RJ45 connector.

Comment: Quite literally, what does this involve: `if there's 4 devices, and the user select Device A and Device D as the beginning and the end`

Comment: So for example there's 4 of the same PCBs and each of them has a CAN bus, and all of them are daisy-chained, and the user  will be able to select like Device A is the first device, so activate the 120 ohm resistors, and same goes to Device D.

Comment: There is no point of wasting MCU resources for that. The topology is built physically and not programmatically. So the bus configuration should be done physically as well

Comment: Have the user plug in a terminator cable or plug to unused ports? That makes sure the user configures the connections correctly while doing connections. The resistors can still be on the PCB, just have a plug that connects CAN pair to resistor.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually in CAN it's relatively common for devices to have selectable (via software or via e.g. jumper) termination enable/disable. Normal with data loggers, DAQs, test rigs, etc. The topology can be dynamic based on what's plugged into the bus.

Comment: @cy1125 so what's the real problem then?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm wondering how to activate and deactivate the termination resistors through microcontroller

Comment: @TypeIA Do you know any method using software?

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/485915/selectable-can-bus-split-termination and https://www.maxlinear.com/appnote/an212_rs485-termination-resistor-switch-solution_080911.pdf

Comment: Since you don't switch it on/off "on the fly" then simply use a MOSFET.